# When spying on component method, called from componentDidMount, the spy is never called

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

In a React component I have

```
export default class MyComp extends Component {
  ...
  componentDidMount() {
    this.customFunc();
  }
  customFunc = () => {
    // ..
  }
  ...
}
```

And when I try to test this method with Jest and Enzyme like this:

```
it('Should call customFunc on mount', () => {
  const MyCompInstance = mount(<MyComp {...props} >).instance();
  const spy = jest.spyOn(MyCompInstance, 'customFunc');

  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

it fails with `Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.`

The funny thing is that if I put `console.log()` in `componentDidMount` and in `custsomFunc` - they get called.
What am I doing wrong?

PS: I tried with `forceUpdate` on the instance, right before the expect, but I still get the same error.

Comment: And when you have MyCompInstance().componentDidMount(); before the expect line, what happens then?

Comment: Then probably it'll work :D … but isn't the point to check whether the `customFunc` method will be automatically called, once the component gets mounted/rendered ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> it fails with `Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.`
>
> The funny thing is that if I put `console.log()` in `componentDidMount` and in `custsomFunc` - they get called.

Calling `mount` renders the component and `componentDidMount` gets called as part of that process, which in turn calls `customFunc`.

The `spy` then gets created on `customFunc` but by that time it is too late since `componentDidMount` and `customFunc` have already run as part of `mount` and the test fails with the `spy` reporting that it was not called.

---

> What am I doing wrong?

You need to create the `spy` on `customFunc` *before* it gets called.

This is very difficult the way the code is currently written since `customFunc` is implemented as an *instance property*.

Because it is an instance property it won't exist until the instance exists but the instance gets created during the rendering process which ends up calling `componentDidMount`.

In other words, you need an instance to spy on `customFunc`, but `customFunc` gets called as part of creating the instance.

In this scenario the only way to check if `customFunc` is called when `componentDidMount` runs is to call it *again* after the instance has been created and the component has rendered, which is kind of a hack:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

class MyComp extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.customFunc();
  }
  customFunc = () => { }  // instance property
  render() { return <div/> }
}

it('Should call customFunc on mount', () => {
  const instance  = mount(<MyComp />).instance();
  const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'customFunc');  // spy on customFunc using the instance
  instance.componentDidMount();  // call componentDidMount again...kind of a hack
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();  // SUCCESS
});
```

---

The alternative is to implement `customFunc` as a *class method*.

If `customFunc` is a class method then it will exist on the `prototype` of the class which allows you to create a spy on `customFunc` *before* the instance gets created during the render process in `mount`:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

class MyComp extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.customFunc();
  }
  customFunc() { }  // class method
  render() { return <div/> }
}

it('Should call customFunc on mount', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(MyComp.prototype, 'customFunc');  // spy on customFunc using the prototype
  const wrapper = mount(<MyComp />);
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();  // SUCCESS
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot :) ... I made `customFunc` a class method and not instance method. And indeed - I'm not calling it from somewhere outside the class (some onClick handler for example) - and so no need to be instance method and it auto-binds `this`.

Comment: Very well explained